# Finding whether a piecewise function is even or odd

Tags: functions, fourier-series

A periodic function with period $2\pi$ is defined by $f(x)=1$ in the interval $ a\lt x \lt b$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere.

Can the function be even or odd? If not why not and if so, for what values of $a$ and $b$?

I know that $f(-x)=f(x)$ is even and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ is odd. However, I can't see a way to apply this rule here to find a solution. I don't know any other way of figuring out whether a function is even or odd, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? How could this function be periodic if it is zero everywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your definition of the function is for the interval $[0,2\pi)$ and $0<a<b<2\pi$, so that the function  has period $2\pi$.
Now note that the function cannot be odd since it is always $\ge 0$. It can be even if $2\pi -b =a$.

If the definition is for an interval $[\alpha,\alpha+2\pi)$ you have  to translate of $\alpha$ and you find: $b=2(\alpha+\pi)-a$ and the function is even if $\alpha=k\pi$.

Comment: Yes! Sorry... stupid typo!

Comment: How can we be certain that it is within the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, or that it starts specifically at 0? It just states is that the period of the function is $2\pi$.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. Ihope it can be usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

It surely cannot be odd for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ because $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x) = 1$ for some $x$, but never $f(x) = -1$.

By periodicity we can assume that $a,b \in [-\pi; \pi)$. Now $f$ is even for all values $a,b$ such that $a=-b$. That is because for all $c \in (-b,b)$ we get that f(c) = 1 = -f(c).